# zfs, encrypted home and subfolder file systems

Tags: 16.04, encryption, home-directory, ecryptfs, zfs

I'm trying to migrate my old mdarray `/home` to zfs.

I've created a zpool mirror on the drives that where previously `/dev/md0`.
I've mounted it to `/home` and copied the old `/home/user` folder into it.

```
root@computer:~# zfs list
NAME                   USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
homepool              63,7M  1,76T  61,6M  /home
homepool/user         1,73M  1,76T  1,64M  /home/user
homepool/user/old       96K  1,76T    96K  /home/user/old
```

I've set up two sub-partitions as above, to be able to have different zfs settings for different data, but this is conflicting with how ubuntu encrypted home works.

```
root@computer:~# ls /home/user
Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop  old  README.txt
```

Is zfs on encrypted subfolders a complete no-go?
Is the zfs properties on `homepool/user`applied at all after ecryptfs is mounted on that name?

I rearranged the partitioning like so:

```
root@computer:~# zfs list
NAME                 USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
homepool             254G  1,51T  1,66M  /home
homepool/.ecryptfs   254G  1,51T   254G  /home/.ecryptfs
```

It feels like it would atleast work.

Are there any recommendations for how to do encrypted home and zfs in ubuntu at this time? Maybe normal luks disk encryption on the drives and zfs on the encrypted volumes make more sense?

Comment: ZFS encryption is inheritable to descendent file systems. You can set an encryption policy when a ZFS file system is created, but the policy cannot be changed. I hope this is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to decrypt data and create zfs pool using LUKS encryption disks. You can move data to encypted ZFS pools. 
You can check out following sources.

https://www.ubuntu-user.com/Magazine/Archive/2013/16/Encrypted-ZFS-with-Ubuntu

https://www.makethenmakeinstall.com/2014/10/zfs-on-linux-with-luks-encrypted-disks/

http://www.fyzix.net/index.php?title=Setting_up_an_Encrypted_RAID_with_Ubuntu-ZFS%2BLUKS